# How to post data using AFNetworking 2.0 with application/x-www-form-urlencoded HttpHeaderField

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

I am going to convert NSURLConnection to AFNetworking 2.0. When I use NSURLConnection to post data that works fine. But I have no idea of how to do it with AFNetworking 2.0.

Here is code snip of NSURLConnection request.

```
#define API_URL @https://myurl.com//login.php"

#define LOGIN_POST_TYPE @"app_data={\"app_data\":{\"user\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}}"
+(void) post:(NSString*)api AndPostData:(NSData*)postData AndCallback: (void (^)(id result, NSError *error))callback {

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
        if ([data length] >0 && connectionError == nil)
        {
            NSString *dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            callback([dataStr JSONValue], nil);
        }
        else
        {
            callback(nil, connectionError);
        }
    }];

}


+(void) callAPIWithType:(int)apiType withParams:(NSDictionary *)param andCallback:(void(^)(id result, NSError *error)) callback
{

NSString *strPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:LOGIN_POST_TYPE, param[@"email"], param[@"password"]];

NSLog(@"%@", post);

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    [self post:API_URL AndPostData:postData AndCallback:^(id result, NSError *error) {
         callback(result, error);
    }];
}
```

Like I said, this code works fine. But how do I convert this code to AFNetworking 2.0?
I tried a lot with AFNetworking. But all of ways are not working for me. 
I get error response.

What and how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of the code I use, but changed to match your request, your postData just needs to be an `NSDictionary` not `NSData`...

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];

[manager POST:@"https://myurl.com//login.php" parameters:postData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

  // responseObject contains the result

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"%@ failed: %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]),operation.responseObject);

}];
```